# SQL checking DateTime difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a datetime column and a stored procedure that should check the difference between the passed argument to the column's datetime.

Basically, I want to return the differences with more or less than 5 minutes.

For example, I have the following table:

```
ID | Date
----------
1  | 2013-07-20 10:00:00
2  | 2013-07-20 11:00:00
3  | 2013-07-20 10:01:00
4  | 2013-07-20 10:03:00
```

If the passed argument, for example, is "2013-07-20 10:02:00", the return value should be

```
1
3
4
```

Because they are all in the scope of the 5 minutes less or more than the passed argument.

Now the question is, how to?

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: In response to the answers using `Abs()` with `DateDiff()` - this will stop the optimizer from being able to use any indexes on the `[Date]` field.

Comment: Just for the fun of it: `SELECT getdate(),
 cast(cast(getdate() AS FLOAT) + .003472222222 AS DATETIME),
 cast(cast(getdate() AS FLOAT) - .003472222222 AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2013-07-20 10:02:00';

SELECT id
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_field >= DateAdd(mi, -5, @date)
AND    date_field <  DateAdd(mi, +5, @date);
```

Comment: datediff used by the other answers will not give the exact 5 minutes, so +1 for this answer. This will also perform faster on a huge table

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE ABS(DateDiff(minute,@date,Date))<=@diffMin
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3ea8/2/0)